# ZUUIRevealController leaks memory?

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-management

I am using ZUUIRevealController in my project. It seems that memory is not freed properly.
I took the sample from GitHub and checked it in instruments. Each time i click in frontview controller, it shows increase in #living column.

Can anyone help to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was in fact a leak due to a superfluos colon at the end of a selector name.

This should be fixed now and we're back to being 100% clear.

See https://github.com/pkluz/ZUUIRevealController/commit/c213c46e505a813202c6a7718f64c72d0c19b06d for further reference.

Comment: Thank you wasabi. We already figured it out . Was about to post answer.  One more information is that view will appear is not called for 4.0 version. May be you will be interested to solve that too. Also in 4.0 iPad version view is not correctly re-sized while switching between menu and front view. One last comment -- ZUUIRevealController is really cool and saved us a lot of time . Great work.

Comment: First of all thanks for great library. Can you help me with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13966366/zuuirevealcontroller-memory-allocations-keeps-on-increasing-slow-uialertview