# ZUUIRevealController - Memory allocations keeps on increasing & slow UIAlertView & UIActionsheet

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, ios6, uialertview, uiactionsheet, sidebar

I am starting with new iOS app in which I have to use Reveal control. So I planned to use great ZUUIRevealController library. I just created UI for 2 - 3 screens . In one of those screen I have to shown UIAlertView & UIActionsheet. But I realised that **UIAlertView & UIActionsheet shows very slowly** (it adds black overlay first & then shows UIAlertView/UIActionsheet, kind of alert view hangs while showing. Animation is not smooth). I didn't added any logic for coding just created the UI. I didn't use any background thread / dispatch_asyn(). So there is no issue of updating UI from background thread. So I checked the memory leaks & allocations. I didn't see any memory leaks , but memory allocations keeps on increasing while I reveal the menu & push new view controller. It doesn't decrese when I pop the view controller. Here are the screenshots :

1) When app launches
[image]

2) After some time , when I push new view controller, pop view controller

[image]

I know ZUUIRevealController library creates new instance of view controller every time I select a row from Menu. So I crated the instance variables of view controllers in .h file , but still I have same problem.

Here is my code

//  AppDelegate.m
// On SplashViewController , I decide whether to show menu or Login screen

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.splashViewController = [[SplashViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SplashViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.splashViewController;

    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    [self customizeUIControlsAppearance];
    return YES;
}
```

//  SplashViewController.m

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    BOOL isLoggedIn = YES;
    if(isLoggedIn){
        [self showMenuViewController];
    }
    else{
        [self showStartUpViewController];
    }
}

-(void)showStartUpViewController
{
    StartUpViewController *startUpViewController = [[StartUpViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"StartUpViewController" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *navController=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:startUpViewController];
    [self presentViewController:navController animated:NO completion:^{

    }];
}

-(void)showMenuViewController
{
    MenuViewController *menuViewController=[[MenuViewController alloc] init];
    CategoryViewController *categoryViewController=[[CategoryViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"CategoryViewController" bundle:nil];
    categoryViewController.isViewControllerShownFromMenu = YES;
    UINavigationController *navController=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:categoryViewController];
    RevealController *revealController=[[RevealController alloc] initWithFrontViewController:navController rearViewController:menuViewController];
    [self presentViewController:revealController animated:NO completion:^{

    }];
}
```

//  MenuViewController.m

// SettingsViewController & NewsViewController are decalred in .h file with property & syntheszie

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    RevealController *revealController = [self.parentViewController isKindOfClass:[RevealController class]] ? (RevealController *)self.parentViewController : nil;

    // Switch using Section Number
    switch (indexPath.section) {
        case OTHER_SECTION:
            switch (indexPath.row) {
                case NEWS:
                    [self showNewsViewControllerUsingRevealController:revealController];
                    break;
                case SETTINGS:
                    [self showSettingsViewControllerUsingRevealController:revealController];
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

}

#pragma mark - Show News & Settings View Controllers

-(void)showNewsViewControllerUsingRevealController:(RevealController*)revealController
{
    if ([revealController.frontViewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]] && ![((UINavigationController *)revealController.frontViewController).topViewController isKindOfClass:[NewsViewController class]])
    {
        if(!self.newsViewController)
            self.newsViewController = [[NewsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NewsViewController" bundle:nil];
        self.newsViewController.isViewControllerShownFromMenu = YES;
        UINavigationController *navigationController= [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.newsViewController];

        [revealController setFrontViewController:navigationController animated:NO];
    }
    else
    {
        [revealController revealToggle:self];
    }
}

-(void)showSettingsViewControllerUsingRevealController:(RevealController*)revealController
{
    if ([revealController.frontViewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]] && ![((UINavigationController *)revealController.frontViewController).topViewController isKindOfClass:[SettingsViewController class]])
    {
        if(!self.settingsViewController)
            self.settingsViewController= [[SettingsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SettingsViewController" bundle:nil];
        self.settingsViewController.isViewControllerShownFromMenu = YES;
        UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.settingsViewController];

        [revealController setFrontViewController:navigationController animated:NO];
    }
    else
    {
        [revealController revealToggle:self];
    }
}
```

// Code for shwoing UIAlertView & UIActionsheet

```
-(void)showAlertWithTitle:(NSString*)title andMessage:(NSString*)message
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:title message:message delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];
}

-(void)btnInviteTapped:(id)sender event:(UIEvent*)event
{
    UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc]initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"FRIENDS_VC:INVIT_ACTIONSHEET_TITLE", nil) delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"FRIENDS_VC:ACTIONSHEET_CANCEL_BUTTON",nil) destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:NSLocalizedString(@"FRIENDS_VC:ACTIONSHEET_SMS_BUTTON",nil),NSLocalizedString(@"FRIENDS_VC:ACTIONSHEET_EMAIL_BUTTON",nil), nil];
    actionSheet.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent;
    [actionSheet showInView:self.view];
}
```

By the way I have **11 menu items**.

**My Login & Regsiter flow is not embedded in MenuViewController. On Login & REgsiter , UIAlertView & UIActionSheet shows smoothly.**

Any idea whats going wrong here ? Did I make some mistake in coding ?
Why my UIAlertView & UIActionsheet are not showing smoothly ?
Any kind of help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I currently don't really have a chance to look further into this but you just for your information: You're not required to constantly create new instances of those view controllers, as you can save them yourself in your own properties, thus also preserving state and preventing reallocations.

Comment: Thanks for reply.I created the properties of my view controllers in my .h file. Still memory allocations keeps on increasing. Did I make some mistake in above code?Thanks